# Angular $scope.$apply exceptions when maximing a Malhar widget

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, widget

I am working in the Malhar widget framework, which is based on jQuery sortable widgets. ex/ https://github.com/DataTorrent/malhar-angular-dashboard

I am working on some DOM manipulation on each widget (maximize/minimize/refresh), and running into some `Angular $scope.$apply` exceptions below.

- Function details:

The `$scope.grabSouthResizer` function (working fine) is the `Mahlar` function that came with the framework; I just modified it slight to also refresh the `Kendo UI charts`.

The `$scope.maxResizer` function is my custom function, which is throwing `$rootScope:inprog` exceptions every time is hits my `$scope.$apply();`.

```js
$scope.grabSouthResizer = function (e) {
 var widgetElm = $element.find('.widget');

 e.stopPropagation();
 e.originalEvent.preventDefault();

 // get the starting horizontal position
 // .. code ommitted for brevity

 // sets new widget width on mouseup
 var mouseup = function (e) {

  // calculate height change
  var curY = e.clientY;
  var pixelChange = curY - initY;

  var widgetContainer = widgetElm.find('.widget-content');

  var diff = pixelChange;
  var height = parseInt(widgetContainer.css('height'), 10);
  var newHeight = (height + diff);

  $scope.widget.setHeight(newHeight + 'px');

  $scope.$emit('widgetChanged', $scope.widget);
  
  $scope.$apply();  // *** NO EXCEPTIONS THROWN ***

  $scope.$broadcast('widgetResized', {
   height: newHeight
  });
  
  // kendo chart - refresh height               
  var chart = widgetElm.find('.k-chart').data("kendoChart");
  if (chart != undefined) {
   chart.setOptions({ chartArea: { height: newHeight - (newHeight * .10) } });
   chart.resize($(".k-chart"));
  }
 };
 
};

$scope.maxResizer = function (e) {
 // TODO: properly restore the window to original position..      
 
 var widgetElm = $element.find('.widget');

 e.stopPropagation();        // testing - same as grabSouthResizer() below
 e.originalEvent.preventDefault();

 var pixelHeight = widgetElm.height();
 var pixelWidth = widgetElm.width();

 // fyi: '.k-tree' will auto-resize, so no need to find that
 var chart = widgetElm.find('.k-chart').data("kendoChart");
 var treelist = widgetElm.find('.k-treelist').data("kendoTreeList");
 
 // height differential (reduce height of container if inner widget is a treelist)
 var ht_diff = (chart != undefined ? 200 : 600);
 var newHeight = window.innerHeight - ht_diff;

 if (!widget.maximized) {
  // widget container maximize
  widget.maximized = true;

  $scope.widget.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
  $scope.widget.setHeight(newHeight);        //window.innerHeight - ht_diff);

  $scope.$emit('widgetChanged', widget);            
  
  $scope.$apply();  // *** THROWS $rootScope:inprog EXCEPTIONS !!! ***
 
  $scope.$broadcast('widgetResized', {
   width: window.innerWidth,
   height: newHeight      
  });            
           
  if (chart != undefined) {
   // refresh Kendo chart 
   chart.setOptions({ chartArea: { height: widgetElm.height()*.9, width: widgetElm.width()*.95 } });
   chart.resize($(".k-chart"));                    
  }             
 } 
    kendoRefreshTimer(); // this work-around used instead of $scope.$apply()
}
var timer;
    function kendoRefreshTimer() {            
        timer = $timeout(function () {
            refreshKendo();
        }, 1);
    }        

    function refreshKendo() { 
       // Kendo chart refresh here...
    }
```

Big question: why is `$scope.$apply();` causing errors in my `maxResizer` function, but not in the Malhar original `grabSouthResizer` function ? I also understand that `$scope.$apply()` is NOT recommended, but it seems to be widely used as a work-around.

I would create an online plunk, but I still haven't set up this Malhar widget framework online as of yet. It's a bit complicated to set up.

Your advice is appreciated.

regards,
Bob

*** UPDATE ***

I updated my post to show how I've worked around this scope.apply issue by using a `$timeout` function, but I don't like the split-second delay in the UI. i.e. You can see the Kendo chart resizing itself, so it doesn't look so smooth.

Comment: you shouldn't run `$scope.$apply` if that code getting called from angular context..but try with `$timeout(function(){ //add your code here which need digest cycle })`

Comment: @PankajParkar - in fact, I do already have a $timeout function I've implemented as a work-around. It's working fine, but there's a split-second delay when I maximize the widget. So my Kendo bar chart for example goes from smaller to larger to fit the widget container - however you can see the split-second delay as the chart re-renders to a larger size.

Comment: I updated my post to also show the $timeout I've written in place of scope.apply. This has been working for me since last night, but I don't like the chart refresh delay in the UI.